# Where can I find this startup entry

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-registry

I am on Windows 10.  After I re-organised my drives and folders, I get this error on startup.  I get it the first time I logon after booting up.

```
E:\Development\Toolbar is unavailable. If the location is on this PC, 
make sure the device or drive is connected or inserted....
```

[image: Screenshot]

I have a folder with shortcuts of my most often used programs.
rather like a menu. Originally I had created a shortcut this folder in the startup folder.  Since then, I have shifted it and made a new entry in the startup folder.  This starts as expected.

I have searched the registry for `\Development\Toolbar` but there are no hits.  I have also looked at the global and personal startup folders on the Boot Drive. And I have looked at the `Startup Apps` and, under `AppData`.

Is there anywhere else I should look ?

Comment: Use the [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) utility.  It shows ALL startup locations to include task scheduler and explorer shell extensions.

Comment: I ran it and its scary, just how many things run.  I deleted and disabled a whole lot.  But unfortunately, I did not find the culprit.  Maybe I will run Registry First Aid and see if it finds it.

Comment: Added the screenshot.  I haven't tried creating a folder there.  It will open at startup, because it used to open before.

Comment: This is probably something in quick access or one of the other shell folders getting re-assigned to a folder you no longer have.  What happens if you create the path it says it can't find?  Then the explorer might fire up and let you use the intended mechanism to re-assign it rather than hacking our way through.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I recreated that folder.  Once opened, I could find the shortcut.  The path was `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` .  Something I had not expected or searched.  Since idiots are voting for the question to be closed.  I won't bother to post it as answer for future readers !!!

Comment: Sorry.  Glad you fixed it though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a suggestion in the comments, I recreated that folder. Once opened, I could find the shortcut that was the culprit. The path was

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

**Autoruns** did not look in this path, and it does not appear to be a normal location.  I suspect it is been migrated by Windows from an earlier version.